# How to filter queryset using item inside a list in a JSON file in Django?

Tags: python, json, django

I have JSON files that are structured like this in my database:

```
}
    "user" : {
        "contacts" : [
            {
                "type" : "email",
                "data" : "aaa@foo.com"
            },
            {
                "type" : "phone_number",
                "data" : "4444-4444"
            },
            {
                "type" : "email",
                "data" : "bbb@foo.com"
            },
            
            ...
            
        ],
        "name" : "Bob"
    }
}
```

What I want is to filter the queryset so I end up only having users that have an account with an email registered.

Anyone knows how to make this work?

I am aware of `user__contacts__0__type=email` but the list doesn't have a fixed size.

Comment: If the data has such structure, it makes more sense to make extra models and work with `ForeignKey`s: both relation databases and Django doe not work very effectively with JSON blobs.

Comment: The idea is that JSON blobs should be used for *unstructured* data: so where it is unknown what the keys/values/structure will be. Not for data that has a fixed "schema".